# how to hide section title if result not found using searchbar in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, searchbar

[image: IF Name is present then it will look like this]

[image: IF Name is not present then it look like this i want to hide section title if name is not present]

```
-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        return sortedKeys;
    }
    else
    {
       return sortedKeys1;
    }
}
```

I use this code but i don't want section title if name is not present , now its give me all section titles

Comment: Do you try to return 0 number of section?

Comment: yes i return 0 in numberrowsinsection

Comment: I mean in numberofsection, not numberrowsinsection.

Comment: nop i return array their

Comment: Can you post lines where you return in numberofsection?

Comment: see this lines- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
   {
        return ([sortedKeys count]);
   }
    else
    {
        return ([sortedKeys1 count]);
     }
    }

Comment: Do you try to return 0 in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` if `result not found`? Or [sortedKeys count], [sortedKeys1 count] is equal 0 already?

Comment: can you give me code line please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no rows than set the title of the section to nil.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0)
 {
                return nil;
    } else {
        return "section title \(section)"
    }
   return @"";
}
```

This will work.

Comment: Welcome..Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Try return 0 in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { 

     if (result_not_found) { /// pass the condition when "result not found" here
        return 0;
     }

     if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0) { 
        return ([sortedKeys count]); 
     } 
     else { 
        return ([sortedKeys1 count]); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Try this, if the same. Maybe the answer of @vijay is correct.

Comment: yes anhtu , vijay is right its working thank you so much for your help

Comment: you should accept first giver answer if 2 answer are correct

Comment: @NitinGohel, I gave the answer before vijay. But the answer of vijay is correct. Thank you

Comment: both are correct want mark both but only one is selected anhtu

Answer (score 0):

You should either use this one returning the correct number of sections :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

Or this one returning CGFLOAT_MIN if there is no rows in the corresponding section :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Hope it helps.

Tom